# Deploy different branchs with Google Cloud Run

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-run

I want to deploy the test branch of my existing repository named 'engine' using Google Cloud Run, but Cloud Run is not allowing the deployment because the repository is already deployed.

My question is this;

How do we proceed when we want to deploy different branches of a repository? And how can I do this with Google Cloud Run?